# Does EF 6 and higher offer better ways of auditing interactions with the data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've been tasked with developing a means of auditing reads/edits/deletes of data from our databases. I did a search on how to do this with EF. I found this blog post on CodeProject,  [Implementing Audit Trail using Entity Framework Part-1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34491/Implementing-Audit-Trail-using-Entity-Framework-Pa). However, the article was written back in 2009. I'm sure it will work, but I'm wondering if using EF 6 and higher, there might be better ways of doing this? Does EF 6+ have a newer way of getting the necessary data for logging/auditing? Is there a "best practice" type of approach for auditing using EF 6+?

Comment: But why not just use database triggers? As an additional benefit it will log all actions performed on database directly, without EF.

Comment: I've asked to use database triggers. I was told not to. That is why I'm having to seek alternative solutions.

Comment: Hope they also provided some arguments in addition to that "no".

Comment: Take a look at [Audit.EntityFramework](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework#auditentityframework) library.

Answer (score 0):

Auditing can still only be achieving by either implementing yourself or using a third-party library even for EF6 or EF Core.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

This library support EF5, EF6 and EF Core and has multiple MUST-HAVE features like AutoSave in the Database.

```
// using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.

var ctx = new EntityContext();
// ... ctx changes ...

var audit = new Audit();
audit.CreatedBy = "ZZZ Projects"; // Optional
ctx.SaveChanges(audit);

// Access to all auditing information
var entries = audit.Entries;
foreach(var entry in entries)
{
    foreach(var property in entry.Properties)
    {
    }
}
```

Documentation: [EF+ Audit](http://entityframework-plus.net/audit)

Comment: Jonathan, I think it's great that you answer questions like this. Also you always appropriately mention your personal interest (disclaimer). However, I think it would be better to mark questions like these as duplicate of a similar one that you answered before. You could choose one of your answers as a *canonical answer* that you can update whenever you think new information about your library is helpful. The duplicates will serve as signposts to this answer.

Comment: Thank Gert for your feedback. I personally dislike “Duplicate” since they are never personalized to the current user/question, but I will try to mark them more often as duplicate to another of my answer. I will try to do as you mentioned unless the answer requires some code customization.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it's always a fine balance whether or not a question is different enough to merit its own answer. Maybe this one was - your first sentence answers what the OP actually asked. Anyway, four other votes are required before a question really goes down as duplicate, so it doesn't only depend on your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some options, based on what your need is. I think auditing is best done on a database level due to performance and to audit changes made outside the entity framework context. Depending on the Sql Server version and edition you might be able to use build-in features like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx

If you need to include application level data you might be able to include it in combination with using an interceptor (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx#BuildingBlocks.Result)

Another option that comes to mind is writing some auditing logic in an override of SaveChanges (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714(v=vs.100).aspx). This will only affect saves and not reads...